# jar: No such file or directory Github Actions

Tags: java, spring-boot, github-actions, devops, cicd

I want to set up a ci/cd pipline for my Java application using github actions, first job is a normal build

```yaml
build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: 17
          cache: 'maven'

      - name: Build and Package
        run: mvn clean package
```

Second I lunch the deploy :

```yaml
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

    steps:
      - name: Configure SSH
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.VM_HOST }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

      - name: Copy JAR to VM
        run: scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/target/flexipages-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ${{ secrets.VM_USERNAME }}@${{ secrets.VM_HOST }}:/root/artifact2
      # - name: SSH into VM and Restart App
      #   run: |
      #     ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ${{ secrets.VM_USERNAME }}@${{ secrets.VM_HOST }} 'cd /root/artifact && java -jar flexipages-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

A got this not found file error :

```bash
Run scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/target/flexipages-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ***@***:/***/artifact2
  scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/target/flexipages-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ***@***:/***/artifact2
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
/home/runner/work/FlexiPages-backend/FlexiPages-backend/target/flexipages-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

[image]

while debugging I added a step in the build to see the generated jar and everything seems working well

[image]

am I missing something?

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Thanks @aled for the recommendation, I fixed the question format.

Comment: The files (artifacts) generated in one job are not visible to another because the jobs are run in different runners. For a quick fix, you can simply combine both jobs i.e. add `ssh` config and `scp` steps in the same `build` job. For keeping them separate, you may utilize the upload/download artifacts approach, see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts.